# If Statements in IDLE python3.9 Not Functioning Properly

Tags: python, python-idle

[Screenshot of Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiaPR.png)

I'm trying to learn python and was trying out simple if statements in IDLE that comes with the python3.9 installation for macOS Catalina 10.15.7.

I am following along with the beginner guide on Python's own website (https://docs.python.org/3.9/tutorial/controlflow.html) and for some reason the IDLE shell will not allow me to write an elif condition. Whenever I write the first if statement, hit enter, type the code for that condition, and hit enter again, it skips me to the next line and if I try to type and elif or else condition, it gives me a syntax error when I hit enter to go to the next line. I've tried looking this up but, I can't find any information or anyone with similar experiences.

My text looks like this...

`x = int(input("Please enter an integer: "))`

-enter integer-

`if x < 0:`

```
x = 0
print('Negative changed to zero'`
```

Here it goes to a new line and I type...

`elif x == 0:`

and I get an error that just says invalid syntax even though it's forcing me to a new line. Not sure what to do but would appreciate any tips or advice on the issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Your indent is wrong.  Python is very finiky with indents.  Your elif should be flushed with the ```if``` statement

Comment: This was it. Thanks for answering so quickly! I basically just had to hit backspace on the new line and type the elif argument with no indent. Apologies for the ridiculous question!

Comment: The visual misalignment of the 'if' and 'elif' in IDLE's Shell, as in Prune's answer, is a side-effect of entering statements rather than lines, which itself is very good. We are working on fixing this wart soon in future releases of IDLE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. Your indentation for the elif is wrong.
Python is very particular about the indentation.
You are currently doing:

```
if x < 0:
    x = 0
    print('Negative changed to zero')
    elif x == 0:
    print('Zero')
```

Instead you should do:

```
if x < 0:
    x = 0
    print('Negative changed to zero')
elif x == 0:
    print('Zero')
```

Comment: This was it, apologies for such a simplistic question and thank you for the help!

Comment: @joetommy Haha no don't apologise. All part of the learning. Wish you all the best and enjoy learning!

Answer (score 0):

You aren't "out-denting" properly.  Instead of hitting a full return for the elif, you have to backspace over your indent, and continue from there.  Once you get the `>>>` prompt, your `if` statement is closed out; you can't add any `elif` or `else` clause any more.
Your session should look something like this:

```
>>> x = 2
>>> if x < 0:
    x = 0
    print("TRUE")
elif x == 0:
    print("ELIF")
```

Comment: Yes, this was my issue. Once I backspaced the indent after hitting return, it worked. Apologies for such simplistic question and answer!

Comment: No problem.  Once in a while, something this basic is *not* obvious, and the question warrants a place in the archives.